# Partial Rendering of UserControls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I have two `UserControls` uc1 and uc2, uc1 contains a `GricView` and uc2 has a `FormView` inside it. uc2 is embeded inside uc1 like

uc1:

```
<div id=grid>
 <!--GridView-->
</div>
<div id=formview>
 <uc2:asd ID=asdasd/> <!-- this has the formview -->
</div>
```

the problem is when uc1 is called all the events e.g `OnDataBound` of FormView is also called.

How can i avoid that or am i doing some thing (horribly)wrong...

EDIT

uc1 is included in the main page say `Default.aspx`

Yet another edit

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <uc1:asd ID="ucontrol1" runat="server"/>

</asp:Content>
```

code for `uc1`

```
<div class="gridViewDiv">
    <asp:GridView
        DataKeyNames="id"
        ID="gv"
        ItemType="ef.sometable"
        runat="server"        
        SelectMethod="gv_GetAll" 
        OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
      ...
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<div>
   <uc2:asd ID="UserControlForm1" runat="server" Visible="false"  />
</div>
```

code for `uc2`

```
<asp:FormView 
    ID="fv" DataKeyNames="id"
    ItemType="ef.sometable" 
    runat="server"
    SelectMethod="fv_GetItem"
    UpdateMethod="fv_UpdateItem"
    InsertMethod="fv_InsertItem"
    OnItemCommand="fv_onItemCommand"
    OnInit="FormViewControl_Init"
    OnDataBound="FormViewControl_DataBound"
    >
```

`uc2` is initially hidden, now when i load `Default.aspx` the events of `FormView` i.e. in  `uc2` are called how can i avoid that or its normal behaviour ....

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you mean by "when uci1 is called".  Called how?  Do you mean when the control is rendered?  Why don't you want the internal formview's control to render?  are uc1 and uc2 bound to the same data source?

Comment: @ErikTheViking i have made the edit to clarify, by refresh i mean when i refresh the Default.aspx in which the `uc1` is included

Comment: You don't mention refreshing in your question.  Your question still doesn't provide enough information to even understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Can you post the code for your default, uc1 and uc2 controls. That way people would be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: @ErikTheViking sry for the ambiguity, in the question i said when `uc1` is loaded... by that i mean when the page that contains `uc1` is refreshed ... hope its clear now im gona post the code for both the controls in a bit

Comment: @ErikTheViking i have edited the question plz have a look